# docker compose fail; SSH to host doesn't work any more

Tags: linux, ssh, docker, docker-compose, crash

I have a Proxmox-VM on this VM runs Rocky Linux and docker with all basic plugins.

- Rocky Linux 8.6 (Green Obsidian)
- Docker 20.10.21
- Docker compose v2.12.2

If I try to run the command docker compose up, sometimes my SSH connection to this VM crashes and I can't reconnect to this VM. But on Proxmox i can see, that this VM ist still online and works normal(other docker container that are still running, keep running and are availible).

Does anyone have a similar problem? You can work like this, but I would still like to know what the problem is exactly and whether I can prevent it. I can also connect via Proxmox Webinterface to this VM, if I enter a docker compose down, I can reconnect to the VM via SSH. Thanks for every answer and sorry for my bad english(not my nativ language)

Best regards

Fabian

Comment: When working with unstable SSH-connections, first thing you do after you connected via SSH, you start `screen`, it's a local shell, which will remain running, even if SSH connections is broken. It has very high default timeout settings and is able to stabilize your SSH connection. Should SSH connection break anyway, you can reconnect to your screen shell session by using `screen -r` after reconnecting SSH. For more info read `man screen`.

Answer (score 0):

In my case,
(1) I allocate 172.0.0.x to my VM
(2) I use VPN Network with TransitGW (192.0.0.x/16) & Add VM Subnet Routing Tables
(3) Run "docker-compose up -d" inside VM
=> After this, VM looks like alive but cant ssh conn.

Problem was Docker Network Allocation!

docker-compose allocate 192.0.0.x/16 range ip to container. It make to conflict  VPN Networks and fail to ssh conn.

Solution was changing Docker Allocating IP Range.

vim /etc/docker/daemon.json
{
"bip": "10.10.0.1/24",
"default-address-pools":
[
{"base":"10.10.0.1/16","size":24}
]
}

systemctl restart docker

Answer (score 0):

Are all the images up-to-date?

Try `docker-compose pull`